# Is it possible to remove css that has been inherited from another css file

Tags: css, qlikview

I am trying to bring two third party tools together QlickView and Telerik Kendo, to create a extension for a report but I seem to have a clash on a bit of CSS. I can get Kendo controls to work in QlickView fine but Kendo buttons are not aligning properly.

When looking in the inspector on chrome if I turn off a padding CSS elements the control works fine. I cannot edit the CSS of either tool. Is it possible to set something in my own CSS file to correct the conflicting css?

[image: CSS causing the issue]
[image: Miss aligned button]

Unticked button to remove the padding setting.

[image: Padding Removed]
[image: Button looks fine]

[Update]

Following what CSSBurner suggested I looked at the CSS applied to the button again and I can see this.

[image]

I think this issue is that the unset is now overwriting the set that is required. Would it be best to just set the padding on the more specific `.QvFrame .k-button` to mimic the `k-button`

[Update 2]

This is what I currently have, if I used the unset it also overrides the `.k-button`. At the moment I have just applied the padding as below and it looks correct.

[image]

```
.QvFrame .k-button {
padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: No - the unset!important is not being applied b/c .QvFrame button selector is more specific. Can you include a rule in your stylesheet with selector .QvFrame button? (not .QvFrame .k-button)

Comment: If I do that will it apply to all .QvFrame buttons? I only want it to affect the Kendo buttons (.k-button) The image might not be clear but its only not using the .QvFrame .k-button unset because I unticked the box in dev tools. It then used .QvFrame button. If I untick that it uses the .k-button

Comment: These selectors will have higher specificity and target only .k-button ----> (a) .QvFrame button.k-button (this assumes the .k-button class is applied to the button element itself ... make sure this is the case or this approach won't work) or (b) .QvFrame button:is(.k-button) -----> (a) is preferable b/c :is() doesn't have full browser support yet (89%; see https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ais() )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either:

1. Add a rule with higher `specificity` in the stylesheet you have control of
2. Override the rule with a rule of your own

Approach #2 IMO is a better choice in this case because it may not be possible to make the selector you listed above more specific. This should work:

```
/* Your stylesheet */
.QvFrame button {
    padding: unset!important
}
```

Using the `unset` keyword will reset the padding to its initial default value. See https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#valdef-all-unset for more information.

Comment: I will update the question, I have made something that is more selective and applied the unset but I think the issue is there is a padding set by k-button that is overridden by .QvFrame button. I will put a screenshot in the question

Comment: Let me add more good articles for CSS specificity: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp, https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ plus a calculator https://specificity.keegan.st/